# Manchester decoding with variable size frames

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm attempting to decode a manchester-encoded packet using GNU Radio Companion. I've been following [this example](https://pmo.io/blog/playing-with-somfy-solus-receiver-part.html) where the author decodes packets from a Somfy window blinds remote. From what I've read in that article and this [mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2008-12/msg00187.html), the Viterbi Combo block is the way to perform manchester decoding.

The Viterbi Combo block requires the block size (frame size) beforehand. This isn't a problem in the case of [the first article](https://pmo.io/blog/playing-with-somfy-solus-receiver-part.html) because the frame size is fixed and known beforehand. In my case, however, the frame size is variable and conveyed in the first octet of the header. i.e.

```
[preamble][sync][header][data][crc]
```

There are several blocks for extracting length information out of a stream, but these assume that the manchester decoding has already been done. Is there a way to do manchester decoding without knowing the block size? Is this a case where I need to make my own custom block?

Comment: I Also don't know how to decode manchester... This guide ( https://nccgroup.github.io/RFTM/fsk_receiver.html ) just says manchester and sort of inexplicably assume that the ClockSync block would decode (for that I don't see no reason);
+1 Q. I'm on the verge of writing my own python code for this rather simple process.

Comment: I ended up writing my own C program that read from a named-pipe. It actually did the clock recovery at the same time. It's not the orthodox way to do things, but it was simple and it worked for me.

Comment: I'm also doing just that in python (working on it) can you post? (Here is the start of mine, still WOP https://pastebin.com/cBFgRRiP  )